# select rows from Dataframe based on aggregated value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame of patient information that is keyed by patient/visit.  I want to select all patient/visit data for patients that have only one visit.  In general I'd like to be able to select data based on any grouped and aggregated value of that data.

My current way to do it is to merge, but that is rather cumbersome.

```
dfg = dfmn.groupby(['pt_studyid']).size().to_frame("count").reset_index()
dfgu = dfg[dfg['count']>1]
dfmn_filt = dfgu.merge(dfmn, on=['pt_studyid']).drop('count', 1)
```

Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Can you post df.head()?

Comment: Feel free to upvote as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `filter` method of the `DataFrameGroupBy` object

```
dfmn.groupby('pt_studyid').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
```

***Example***

```
dfmn = pd.DataFrame(dict(pt_studyid=list('AAAABBBCDEFFF'), val=range(13)))
dfmn

   pt_studyid  val
0           A    0
1           A    1
2           A    2
3           A    3
4           B    4
5           B    5
6           B    6
7           C    7
8           D    8
9           E    9
10          F   10
11          F   11
12          F   12
```

***Filter***

```
print(dfmn.groupby('pt_studyid').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1))

   pt_studyid  val
0           A    0
1           A    1
2           A    2
3           A    3
4           B    4
5           B    5
6           B    6
10          F   10
11          F   11
12          F   12
```